# Locating php.ini on Amazon Linux

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services

This question has been asked many times before, but my php.ini file seems to be not present.

I installed php 5.6.2 by compiling from [source](http://museum.php.net/php5/) on Amazon Linux machine. It seems to be installed well.

`which php` gives

```
/usr/local/bin/php
```

`php --ini` gives

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

When I enter `/usr/local/lib`, there is no php.ini present. Am I supposed to create a new php.ini file myself?

Comment: This may help you http://serverfault.com/questions/564636/amazon-linux-php-5-5-php-ini-ignored

Comment: you can check in /etc/php.d
or if you are using php-fpm than in etc/php-fpm.d/

Comment: Run this command `php -i | grep "Configuration File"` hope it will help you.

Answer (score 4):

On my server it is located in `/etc/php.ini`

Comment: This is the path of the Amazon Linux 2 for the php.ini

Comment: Only this answer worked to fix the limited upload file size limit of wordpress and this question doesn't even come in search results when you type wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

php.ini file found here:

`/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini`

You can change the values here and then restart the Apache Server.

It will perfectly work.

I have created a complete tutorial for this.

Please have a look at [php.ini aws ec2 tutorial](https://8subjects.com/3-easy-steps-to-change-php-configuration-in-aws-ec2-ubuntu-server-php-ini-ec2/)